Properties of PI controller with stabilities question
PI controller was built according to the manual shown in the link.
From its bode plot we have 180 degrees at 8 kHz.
few questions: \

Does it matter if its -180 degrees or +180 when we calculate gain margin?

In 15 MHz I see that gain 0 dB and 77 degrees.
How do I see the phase margin in this point.

When I did a time domain simulation I see an overshoot .
How can I compare the gain and phase margins with the step response.
Thanks.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Bo3xcPQX8Y








R3 = 100 TOhm is a "big" value. Choose one which can be "usual" (1-10 MOhm).

R3 is irrelevant, In the manual uses it  as a precaution so the simulation would run. I didnt put it into  LTSPICE simulation .

My latest version  of LTSpice required R3. I also had 20% overshoot faster.  Something is wrong with your Gain plot showing a notch.  You get even less damping if you add k after R values. with much higher Q resonance and ringing.  https://i.sstatic.net/V0laCkJt.png  https://i.sstatic.net/tC0TBfWy.png

It's basically an inverting amplifier (equivalent to 180° of phase shift) so, to calculate gain margin you use the 0° phase shift point and, as you can see, the gain is much less than unity: -

At unity gain the phase margin is about 80°: -

Be careful about judging overshoot if you didn't realize that the zero phase shift point was the point at which gain margin was calculated.

Hello Andy, Why did you say that its 0 phase shift and not -180.In the manual they say its -180.

For a non-inverting amplifier, the phase margin is calculated when the output is 180 degrees phase shifted (i.e. inverting). Your circuit is naturally inverting in its main operating area (mid-band) so, you need to determine phase margin relative to the 0 degrees shifted point (when gain is 0 dB) @user451625

If it has 20% overshoot then the phase margin must be less than 50 degrees.  The plot looks non-linear with the notch which looks wrong.

Hello Andy, So If its an inverting amplifier ,zero phase shift and 0dB is the point of instability , this is for gain margin.
About phase marging we go to 0dB and we need to compare the phase to 0 degrees, thats why its 80 degrees.
Thanks.

@user451625 correct, and, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Hello Andy ,given the method you showed I tried to see the lack of phase and gain margins.In the time domain simulation we clearly see the system oscillating.
How can I looks in the AC responce and see that tis system will oscilate?
The highest point in gain is -44dBm , why its osclitaing?Thanks.
https://ibb.co/mGQTr1s
https://ibb.co/0rkVFnz
https://ibb.co/WxF4CQ9

It won't oscillate all by itself so, I recommend you raise a new post showing how you used the circuit within a feedback loop.

Hello Andy, I showed in the links a circuit which is oscillating while I dont even have 0dB in the gain.The circuit is AC responce for I(L1) inductor loop.My question is how can I see that the circuit would oscillating in the AC response? Thanks.
https://ibb.co/mGQTr1s
https://ibb.co/0rkVFnz
https://ibb.co/WxF4CQ9

You should raise a new post. After all, this is a question and answer site and, you'll get a bigger immediate audience. Supplementary questions in comments are not really a good fit especially if needing a bit of work in analysing and responding with possible images.
